# How do I get a callback URL to Identity/Pages/Account/ConfirmEmail from a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got a scenario where I want to generate an email confirmation URL the same way as in the Register page of the Identity area ("Identity/Pages/Account/Register"). I've already scaffolded the Identity area and have access to its Pages.

I need this to happen from a controller located in a completely different area.
I try to do something similar as in Register.cshtml.cs but instead of using Url.Page I use Url.Action (we're located inside a controller remember).

The problem is that the following code generates a null string which is not exactly what we are after:

```
string confirmationLink = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail",
                        "Account", new
                        {
                            area = "Identity",
                            userid = viewModel.User.Id,
                            token = code
                        },
                        protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
```

What am I possibly doing wrong here? This is located in

> /Areas/CompanyUsers/Controllers/HomeController.cs.

Please refrain from commenting on the idea of generating this url from a "random" controller. I need a way of registering users from an already authenticated user (A company owner user must have the ability to register users into the application without them needing to use the default Identity way of doing this.).

Comment: The way I made this work on one of my projects is that after scaffolding the Identity Artifacts I converted Pages to Views and Controllers.  After that it worked.  That  is how I did it.  Plus I hate the idea of having Pages and normal MVC in the same website seems kind of eclectic in my opinion.

Comment: My scenario was the same as yours.... An Admin would create users and then they would get a password reset link on an email

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Url.Action` is for generating URLs for *actions*, but `ConfirmEmail` is a *page*. Use `Url.Page` to generate the correct URL:

```
string confirmationLink = Url.Page(
    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
    null, // handler
    new { area = "Identity", userid = viewModel.User.Id, token = code },
    Request.Scheme);
```